# How to determine which overloaded function is called?

Tags: c++, overloading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float f (int a, int b) {
    return (a + b);
}

float f (float a, float b) {
    return (round(a + b));
}

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    int int1 = 1;
    int int2 = 2;
    float float1 = 1.2f;
    float float2 = 1.4f;
    cout << f(int1, int2) << endl;     // output: 3
    cout << f(float1, float2) << endl; // output: 2
    cout << f(int1, float2) << endl;   // output: 2
    return 0;
}
```

1. Why the last output uses the second definition of `f`?
2. In general, how to determine which overloaded function definition will be used, when there is not an exact matching of the number and types of the arguments between the function definitions and the function call?

Comment: I think you meant: `float float1 = 1.2;` and `float float2 = 1.4;`

Comment: My straight answer would be that `int -> float` is a better conversion than `float -> int`. Interestingly I have not been able to find a quote in the standard where this is stated.

Comment: What compiler/version are you using? After verifying the standard, I believe that the code should trigger an error as the call `f( int1, float2 )` is *ambiguous*. GCC and Clang agree.

Comment: MSVC (10 atleast) actually agrees too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying to determine in the standard why should one overload preferred over the other I have come to the conclusion that it shouldn't, no overload has a better conversion sequence than the other in the case of `f( int1, float2 )` and the code should not compile. If your compiler is accepting it, there might be a bug in the implementation.

As of the second question, the standard defines the conversions that can be used to match a call to a function and it also defines a *rank* for those conversions that serves as a partial ordering (called *better conversion than*). The compiler will always choose the *best* conversion, and if there is no *best* conversion then the program is ill formed as in the example.

**Verification of the ambiguity of the code with different compilers:**

GCC:

```
conv.cpp:22: error: call of overloaded ‘f(int&, float&)’ is ambiguous
conv.cpp:5: note: candidates are: float f(int, int)
conv.cpp:9: note:                 float f(float, float)
```

clang:

```
conv.cpp:22:13: error: call to 'f' is ambiguous
    cout << f(int1, float2) << endl;   // output: 2
            ^
conv.cpp:5:7: note: candidate function
float f (int a, int b) {
      ^
conv.cpp:9:7: note: candidate function
float f (float a, float b) {
      ^
```

MSVS 2010 (Thanks to Xeo):

```
error C2666: 'f' : 2 overloads have similar conversions
          src\main.cpp(2): could be 'void f(int,int)'
          src\main.cpp(1): or       'void f(float,float)'
          while trying to match the argument list '(int, float)'
```

Comment: +1, you can add MSVC10 to the compilers rejecting the code, [here's the error message](http://ideone.com/juukz).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know and more: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/76-function-overloading/

Essentially the second one is selected because if no exact match is possible and no match by promotion is possible, a match by conversion (of the first parameter from `int` to `float`) is done.

Comment: Now the question is where in the standard the `int->float` conversion is considered a better conversion sequence than the `float->int` conversion, both of which are *Floating-integral conversions*

Comment: I doubt float->int is considered better, since you would be losing information.

Comment: We agree on that: it does not make sense to consider better a conversion that can potentially loose information, but that is probably defined somewhere in the standard that I have not been able to find.

Comment: After quite a long time going through the standard, there is no clause that determines the `int->float` conversion to be any better than the `float->int` conversion. The conversion sequences cannot be ordered by the *better* relationship in the standard and the code should not compile. It seems once again, that *common sense* and the standard are not always the same. (I have also verified this with gcc and clang)

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms, if you convert `int` to `float` you lose no information; if you convert `float` to `int` you loose the decimal part of the number. If the compiler cannot find an exact overload match, it will choose the one that causes the least loss of information.